# Raspberry 3 with touch screen and RFID scanner power supply

Tags: power, usb-power, rfid

I have some cheap scanner I'm playing around. It's USB connected and it works.
I wonder can it be safe to make separate power for scanner, bcs allready have touch screen taking power from raspberry and want to see if I can improve performace, and avoid low power warning on raspberry.
So I would deatach 5V and GND wire and connect it to another charger.
Edit:
To add more details, I made tkinter app, it opens serial port, send command to reader and get tag data...
I don't have steady readings always, so not sure from what angle to attack that problem.

Comment: Sounds more like question for Electronics.se, not for this site. You would also need to provide some information on what you are trying to achieve. "Playing around" isn't a good argument for asking such questions, I think.

Comment: use a USB hub ..

Comment: Ty, I have improved code, it reads much faster so it catches tag better.
@jsotola powered hub? I will probably try that.